# The *number* of possible integer solutions to Ax + By + Cz +Dt +... = n

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

I know that for Ax + By = n we have 1 + ${\lfloor}\frac{n}{AB}{\rfloor}$ possible integer solutions when $gcd(A,B)=1$

How do I extend this to N variables?

I'm interested only in the number of possible solutions and not the solutions themselves.

For example if I want to break 100 usd into 1,5,10 and 25 usd notes I would write the equation as : $ x + 5y + 10z + 25w = 100$

How do I go about finding the *number* of possible integer solutions to this?

EDIT: I'm interested in whole number solutions only. (No negatives)

Comment: Thinking of the penultimate sentence, do you mean to restrict to *nonnegative* integer solutions? If $(x_0, y_0)$ is a solution to $A x + B y = n$ then so is $(x_0 - m B, y_0 + m A)$ for all integers $m$, so (for $(A, B) \neq (0, 0)$) if there is one integral solution there are infinitely many.

Comment: @Travis  Ah yes I should have clarified I'm talking whole number solutions only

Comment: How did you arrive at $1 + \lfloor \frac{n}{AB} \rfloor$ solutions for nonegative integers when $gcd(A, B) = 1$? Because there is not always a solution with nonegative integers i.e. $3x + 5y = 7$. Or what am I missing?

Comment: @araomis I got that from a [paper I was reading](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~atripath/publications/ax+by=n.pdf), I should correct myself, quoting from the paper 

*It is well known that N(a,b, n) is always one
of the two consecutive integers ${\lfloor}\frac{n}{AB}{\rfloor}$ or 1 + ${\lfloor}\frac{n}{AB}{\rfloor}$*

I should admit I am not very well versed with Number Theory so I've been having a crack at the references in the paper trying to figure out how that formula was arrived at but with no luck. However I am interested in extending it to N variables